# Adjust automatically the size of div

Tags: css

I have this code, but the `.text` is not working as i expected. The `auto` should fit in the `width` of the container, but the `.text` div will be pushed to a second line. I need the auto value because the width of image can change, and the right div should always fit in the container regardless of image width.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="img"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
    <div class="text">Some text Some textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome text</div>
</div>

.img, .text {
    float:left;
}

.text{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height:150px;
    width:auto; //should be width:248px in this specific case;
}

.container{
    width:600px;
    border:1px solid green;
    height:150px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LCAKw/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don’t let the `.text` class float as well. That way it will be a block element, taking the full width (of the parent element) minus the floating. You might want to apply some left padding then though.

Comment: have you tried padding  and draw borders aside img without overflow (or other adapted rule that modify layout) ?http://jsfiddle.net/LCAKw/12/

Answer (score 0):

`text` seems to be a reserved word, you're not allowed to use as a class name.
After changing it, the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCAKw/1/) works great.

Altered CSS:

```
.text1{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height:150px;
    width:auto;
}
```

Comment: It works, because you didn’t also change the `.img, .text` part where the left float is applied.

Comment: Heh, me too actually ;)

Answer (score 0):

your using `float:left;`  property you should use `width:100%;` instead of `width:auto;` in 
`.text` class and also use `box-sizing:border-box;` if you are using `borders` or `padding`

Answer (score 0):

if .text is not floatting and if its layout is tickled via : `overflow:hidden;` it should work the way you wish
http://jsfiddle.net/LCAKw/5/

Comment: No need to hide the overflow though…

Comment: we call this 'context de formatage' in french , No idea how you call it in english.It is usefull to know so things keeps aside or wrap naturally  floatting elements :) just see where borders are drawn  with and without overflow :)